# Replacing an image in a Google Docs file using Docs REST API with ImageReplaceMethod

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a function that replaces an image in a Docs file using Docs REST API.

The code works, the image is being replaced, but I need to make the image fit in the original image 'placeholder'. Currently the replacement image is being cropped as it's not the same size as the original image it replaced.

The original image is in landscape mode, while the replacement image is in portrait. It looks like the new image is centered horizontally, but it's cropped. So maybe it's behaving correctly, but I incorrectly assume that it will scale the new image so that it fits the original dimensions.

My code:

```
let requests = [];

// Get the Uri of the image file
let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<id of file>?supportsAllDrives=true&fields=webContentLink";
let response = getGoogleAPI(url);
let logoUri = JSON.parse(response).webContentLink;

// Get the id of the image in the Docs file to be replaced
url = "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/<id of file>?fields=inlineObjects";
response = getGoogleAPI(url);

let inlineObjects = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 

for(const key in inlineObjects){
  let objectId = "";

  for(const prop in inlineObjects[key]){
    objectId = inlineObjects[key][prop].objectId;
  }

  requests.push({
    "replaceImage": {
      "imageObjectId": objectId,
      "uri": logoUri,
      "imageReplaceMethod": "CENTER_CROP" //<-- this is where I think I'm missing something
    }
  });
}


// Replace the image
url = "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/<id of file>:batchUpdate";
payload = {
  "requests" : requests
}

response = postGoogleAPI(url, payload);
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the imageReplaceMethod enum correctly, or I do have incorrect assumptions on how this works.

Can anyone enlighten me on this one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike. The image on left is the doc with the image placeholder, the middle image is the logo file that will replace the one in the doc file, and the left image is the result. So the replacement image was stretched to fit the width, vertically cropped.
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J9dLZ2MiedH5vuMr8qcxBgvn6Ey-WKDz/view?usp=share_link).

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested your request body using a sample image and document, the replaced image can be correctly seen. So, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. So, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the sample Document and sample image? And also, can you provide your whole script? Because in your script, there are unknown functions. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. Actually it's me who should thank you for your time. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10IZCWxpF0pMsk52T98p-APJ1TA86LWL8/view?usp=sharing) is the test image. [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h-zrGEfQmHXEp0bNpk2DyTSWz935BoavNPAGRSDn7PM/edit?usp=sharing) is the test Docs file.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can post the entire code due to the character limit, but getGoogleAPI and postGoogleAPI are just wrapper functions to call the REST API. e.g. 
```function postGoogleAPI(url, payload){
  var service = getOAuthService();
  service.reset();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    contentType : "application/json",
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  });

  return JSON.parse(response);
}
```

Comment: I guess you can replace that with what code you use. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

From your provided sample Document, I noticed that your image is put into a table in the header section. And, in the current stage, it seems that when the image is replaced with `replaceImage` of Docs API, the replaced image size depends on the original image size by cropping. I'm not sure whether this is the current specification.

So, in this answer, as a workaround, from your sample Document, I would like to propose that the image is directly changed using a script. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  const documentId = "###"; // Please set the document ID of your Google Document.
  const fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of the image you want to use.

  const h = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getHeader();
  const images = h.getImages();
  if (images.length != 0) {
    const tempImage = images[0];
    const height = tempImage.getHeight();
    tempImage.removeFromParent();
    const cell = h.getTables()[0].getCell(0, 1);
    cell.insertImage(0, DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob()).setHeight(height);
    cell.getChild(0).asParagraph().setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cell.getChild(1).removeFromParent();
  }
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run for your provided sample Document, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided sample Document. When you change the Document, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- If you want to set the replaced image size with the same size (width and height) as the original image size, please modify the above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const height = tempImage.getHeight();
      tempImage.removeFromParent();
      const cell = h.getTables()[0].getCell(0, 1);
      cell.insertImage(0, blob).setHeight(height);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const height = tempImage.getHeight();
      const width = tempImage.getWidth();
      tempImage.removeFromParent();
      const cell = h.getTables()[0].getCell(0, 1);
      cell.insertImage(0, blob).setHeight(height).setWidth(width);
    ```

#### Reference:

- [Class HeaderSection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/header-section)

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. This works but not when deployed and using a service account. It throws an error though I haven't figured out what causes it (maybe permission for the user to access the image and modify the Docs file). Still, it requires the user granting new permissions and I'm trying to avoid that. Maybe there is a way to do this just by using the Docs REST API. Thanks again!

Comment: @Paul Thank you for replying. From `This works`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About `but not when deployed and using a service account.`, I think that when the service account is used, it is required to use Google Docs API. But, from your question and replies, I cannot find that you use the service account. So, in this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. Yes it works, however it does not 100% address my post as it says using Docs REST API. I'm sorry I should have included service accounts. I have accepted your answer though, as it does work and may help anyone in a similar situation. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: @Paul Thank you for replying. About `I should have included service accounts`, in this case, it is required to major change of the script. So, can you post it as a new question? Your this question uses the Document service (DocumentApp). But, in the case of your new situation, it is required to use Google Docs API. By separating questions, I think that it will be useful for other users who have the same issue. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: @Paul By the way, although I'm not sure about your actual situation, in your situation, if the owner of Google Document is the service account and you want to update the Google Document from your account, how about sharing the Document with your account? By this, I think this script might be able to be used. How about this?

Comment: HI @Tanaike. The web app will be used by external users, and they can register by themselves (like an 'ordinary' website') so using a service account to handle the files and folders is more appropriate. No need to maintain the sharing/permissions. But yes, I should post a new question specific to that, but in the meantime I'm considering the option to limit the height of the image that the user uploads, so that it does not go beyond the size in the Docs file. Thanks again!